# Fullcite adds an unwanted comma, how do I fix it?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Here's an MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{thebib.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{thebib.bib}
@article{cavling1892,
author = {Cavling, Henrik},
title = {Jens Nielsens Henrettelse},
journal = {Politiken},
year = {1892},
}
\end{filecontents}

\fullcite{cavling1892}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

You can compile it with

```
xelatex
biber
xelatex
xelatex
```

This is the result of the `fullcite`:
[image: fullcite]

... and here's how it looks with `\printbibliography`: 
[image]

You'll notice that the latter ends with a period, which is more proper. How can I fix the former?

Comment: I don't think you should ‘fix’ it: the context is very different: `\fillcite` is used *within a sentence*, whence a final comma (after the year) which semantically forces no fullstop before, whereas a bibliography entry is a (group of) sentence(s) by itself.

Comment: A comma added at the end of the `fullcite` would not be correct either... But I believe this is the classical case of an entry without fields which the entrytype expects, in this case `volume`/`number`. If your entry really doesn't have one of those, you probably should not use `article` entrytype.

Comment: @gusbrs, this is a newspaper article. I think neither a volume or number should be added but it surely *is* an article. Hurm.

Comment: Ah! Common sense "article" I agree, but BibTeX `@article` is somewhat more specific. But, in this case, biblatex-chicago provides some resources, I'll see if I can sort out an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `article` entrytype, is usually understood in BibTeX entries as something published in an academic journal. This means that `volume`/`number` are expected. That is why a trailing comma is left in the `fullcite` in your example, something that is assumed to be there, isn't. And so, the trailing punctuation is not adequately handled.

As stated in biblatex-chicago's documentation:

> Indeed, by fiat I declare that should you need to refer to a journal that identifies its issues mainly by year, month, or week, then for the purposes of biblatex-chicago-notes such a publication is a "magazine," and not a "journal."

But `biblatex-chicago` provides means to cite/reference newspaper and magazines also through the use of the `article` entrytype, but making use of an entrysubtype, either `newspaper` or `magazine`, which may not have a number.

With it, the result is expected (no end punctuation for the `fullcite`):

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{thebib.bib}
@article{cavling1892,
entrysubtype = {newspaper},
author = {Cavling, Henrik},
title = {Jens Nielsens Henrettelse},
journal = {Politiken},
year = {1892},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{thebib.bib}

\begin{document}

\fullcite{cavling1892}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Oddly, this *still* produces the unwanted comma when I compile it with `xelatex`, `biber`, `xelatex`, `xelatex`. `xelatex --version` gives me `XeTeX 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017)`, `biber --version` gives me `biber version: 2.10`.

Comment: That's odd. I admittedly did not compile with `xelatex`, but I wouldn't expect any difference in this respect to stem from that. What I can think of is: what happens if you delete auxiliary files before compilation?

Comment: This was from a clean slate.

Comment: I'm actually running a TeXlive 2017 too. The versions are the same here. And I do get the result without a comma also with `xelatex`, as expected.